# How can I test if a user input is a decimal with no more than 2 digits after the decimal place?

Tags: vb.net

I'm supposed to make a banking software form that allows a user to create accounts and make deposits and withdrawals for any account. But I cannot figure out how to make it accept an integer, a decimal with only one digit after the dot, or a decimal with the first digit after the dot being a 0.

```
Dim x As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(txtAmount.Text)
If (txtAmount.Text.IndexOf(".") <> -1 And txtAmount.Text.Substring(txtAmount.Text.IndexOf("." + 1)).Length > 2) Then
    MessageBox.Show("No fractions of a penny") 
    Exit Sub                            
End If

Dim a As CAccount = lbxCustomers.SelectedItem
a.deposit(x)
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use Microsoft Masked Edit Control with mask property set to #########.# ?

Comment: You should be using `TryParse` for textbox inputs.

Comment: Please update your question with sample valid and invalid inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Using the tryparse as suggested is most definitely a good starting point.  One simple way to disregard extra digits is with the Truncate method:

```
    Dim x As Decimal
    If Decimal.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, x) Then
        x = Decimal.Round(x * 100) / 100
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Only valid numbers please")
    End If
```

This will leave x with only a maximum of 2 decimal places.  This also rounds the resulting value according to the value in the extra digits.  This is useful for the Decimal type since it is prone to rounding errors and this will even them out.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the current value with the rounded value. If the two are equal, you know there isn't more digits. This won't work if you want to also limit zeros (2.0000 will pass).

```
    Dim val As Decimal

    val = 2.2345

    If val * 100 = Math.Floor(val * 100) Then
        ' Has 2 or less digit
    Else
        ' Has more than 2 digit
    End If
```